# Execute Parallel Jenkins steps and move to next stage independent of the second step state of execution

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to execute Jenkins Pipeline build from legacy Upstream-Downstream jobs.

```
    node () {
stage('Checkout') {
    <Code for checkout> 
    }
stage ('Support') {
    <Restore dependencies>
    <Restore build environment>
    }
    stages{
        parallel{
            stage ('Build and Archive'){
                stages{
                    stage ('BuildSolution') {
                        <Build Solution>
                        }
                    stage ('Signing') {
                        <Sign deliverables>
                        }
                    stage ('InstallerCreation') {
                        <Create deployment package>
                        }

                    stage ('CreateNgPkg') {
                        <Create SDK package>
                        }
                    }
                }
            stage ('SecurityScan'){
                <Execute scan on the complete source code>
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run **stage ('Build')** and **stage ('Scan')** in parallel and after **stage ('Build')** is executed it should start **stage ('CreateNgPkg')** without checking or waiting for **stage ('Scan')**

---

UPDATE:

I tried using the above nested Stages to achieve what i needed but it's giving error "No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps" upon execution. -No syntax error, just this at run time.

Comment: why not add it as a nother parallel job? or do you mean stage("Build") has to finish not only be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to execute the set of stages Build, then CreateNgPkg in parallel with the stage Scan

It translates to the following Jenkins DSL:

```
node () {
    stage ('Checkout') 
    {
        echo 'Checkout'
    }
    stage ('Support') 
    {
        echo 'Support'
    }
    parallel Build: {
        stage ('Build') 
        {
            echo 'build'
        }
        stage ('CreateNgPkg') 
        {
            echo 'CreateNgPkg'
        }
    }, secondStage: {
        stage ('Scan') 
        {
            echo 'scan'
        }
    }
}
```

I personally prefer the declarative dsl which is way better documented and can be linted
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: I tried nested steps as mentioned https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/ but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tries using your syntax and it worked as expected.